# Plotting a cumulative graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to the world of python. I'm trying to create a plot showing accumulated GDD (Growing degree days) vs time for selected cities within a given period of time

I wrote a function to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it to work right. I keep getting with an empty plot in it. Also a dimension error. Anyone know how i can solve these issues.

Any help/suggestions is appreciated!

Here is the code

```
import sys, argparse, csv
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file."""
    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as the_file:
          filename=the_file.read()

    except IOError as err:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", err)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return filename

"""Cities.txt file as an argument"""     
try:
   my_file = open_file(sys.argv[1], 'r')
except:
   print("GDD needs one argument", "\nEnding program...\n")
   input("Press the enter key to exit.")
   sys.exit()


extension=".csv"
for line in my_file.splitlines():
    file_name=line+extension
    print(file_name) 
    with open('data/'+ file_name, "rU") as files:
        val = list(csv.DictReader(files))  
        l = []
    for i in range(0, len(val)):
        row = val[i]
        if row['Min Temp'] == '' or row['Max Temp'] == '':
                pass 
        else:
            GDD = ((float(row['Min Temp']) + float(row['Max Temp']))/2)-10
            l.append(GDD)

            val[i]['GDD'] = GDD

            #print(row['Min Temp'], ' ' , row['Max Temp'], ' ',    str(round(row['GDD'], 2)))

            #plt.subplot(1,1,1)        
            #x = np.linspace(1, 12, 365, endpoint=True)


    x = np.linspace(1, 12, 365, endpoint=True)
    plt.plot(x,GDD, label = file_name.split(',')[0])
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")

    plt.xlabel('Months', color='black')
    plt.ylabel('Cumulative GDD (>10°C)')
    plt.title('Accumulated Growing Degree Days')
    plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast solution could be to add `plt.hold(True)` after a plot call.

A more clean solution is to use a figure which can bee seen as window which you draw onto. [just like in this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html)

So you'd define a figure, keep its reference, add axes and perform all action on these axes

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7])
ax.plot(...)
```